# Display Mic volume in the menu bar

Tags: macos, mojave, menu-bar, microphone

In MacOS Mojave, I want to get the Mic volume icon to the menubar, just like the speaker volume icon. How can I do that?

Like this.

[image]

Comment: There is not a default native way to do it that I know of by just clicking a check box like **[√] Show volume in menu bar** in System Preferences > Sound. The "speaker volume icon" exists because `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu` gets loaded when the checkbox is checked, and there is not one for the Mic. You'd have to either find a third-party app that can do that for you, or roll your own in Xcode if it's possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wanted to share the following app too - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mutekey/id1509590766?mt=12

1. Good UI.
2. Adds icon in the menu bar.
3. Ability to add keyboard hotkey.
4. Can select among input devices.
5. Free.

Same disclaimer as earlier answer: No financial or any other ties to the developer. Just found the app on the app store and love it.

Comment: I prefer this one over the other suggestion primarily because of the ability to use shortcut to mute/unmute. Also, it has a cleaner UI.

Comment: you can set a shortcut to mute/unmute. also use the same shortcut to push tot talk

Comment: Thanks, looks cool!

Answer (score 5):

This app works for me: [MuteMyMic](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mutemymic/id456362093?mt=12). Available in the App Store at that link.

Appears to be free, as well.

It puts an icon in the menubar with a mic input level slider:

[image]

*Disclaimer: no financial or other ties to the developer of this amazing app which I just found using Google.*

Comment: Great answer.  This app also works perfectly with a [Keyboard Maestro shortcut](https://eddmann.com/posts/creating-a-mac-microphone-mute-keyboard-shortcut/) to mute - MuteMyMic is able to show me a red icon when my mic is muted, which was a missing puzzle piece for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

MacOS (Big Sur) actually supports this out of the box.

Simply hold `option` key and `click` on Sound icon on the menu bar.
This will additionally show the microphone settings.

[image]

Simple hidden trick ;)

Comment: The question asks for microphone volume, I don't see that by option-clicking.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but it helped me in my case, so thx anyway :-)

Comment: Is there anything I can set so I don't have to hold `option`?